# Technical correctness of notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I wanted to know if I am writing this correctly.

Consider an index $i$ and a number $N$. And $i,N \in \mathbb{N}$.

I want the index to rotate about N. Say for an increment, $n$, $i+n>N$ then it should output $n-(N-i)$ as the final index. For example, for $N = 4$ and $i = 4$, then $i++ = 1$, and so on.

To achieve this, I defined another index, $j\in\mathbb{N}$, as $j+n = (i+n)\mod N$ so that I can get the indexes to rotate about N without having to change the definition for $i$ at all.

Is my notation correct?

Comment: You could just say that your indexes are in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. For example, as in $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}(x-(i+4))=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}}(x-i)$

Comment: @Hellen Sometimes also denoted by $ℤ_N$.

Comment: @Hellen I don't understand what you've written. Is what I have written wrong? Also, if you could state the sentence that I should write to make it clear that the indexes are circular after $N$. Thanks!